# Type or Namespace Expected in C# 2.0 VS2005

Tags: c#, object

Just wanna create an object of ProgressBar control as below code :

`pgImportProcess process = new pgImportProcess();`

But it occurs an error

**Type or namespace name expected**

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: What is "pgImportProcess"?  It doesn't look like a type name.

Comment: @Oudam, can you provide the scope where you do that operation?  Is pgImportProcess defined and visible inside the executing block?

Comment: @Joe : pgimportProcess is a name of ProgressBar Control , sorry for not detail explanation.

Comment: @Roman : Yes, pgImportProcess have defined in C# windows form as a Progressbar control , and i just wanna create a object from this control and parse it into thread , but it occurs an error **Type or namespace name expected**

Comment: You don't create an object from a control -- a control IS an object.

Comment: I would like to know where you're calling this code from.  If it's within scope of the Form, then you should have access to the pgimportProcess property b/c they are usually defined as protected.  If it's totally outside of the form, then you need to make sure the progress control is a visible property off the form type.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're missing a `using` statement for the namespace that contains the `pgImportProcess` class.

Comment: No , i'm in C# windows form which pgImportProcess have defined as Progressbar Control , sorry for not detail explanation and a bit confusion .

Comment: Then you already have a control and you don't need to `new` up a new one.  Just refer to the one you've got by its name.

Answer (score 0):

The winform progressbar class is located at System.Windows.Forms namespace so you need to write:

```
System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar process=new System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar();
```

EDIT:

@Oudam San:
pgimportProcess is a name of ProgressBar Control , sorry for not detail explanation.

That means reference variable `pgimportProcess` is created (take a look at form designer code). However if you want to instantiate the `ProgressBar` and want to store reference into `pgimportProcess` variable then you may write:

```
pgImportProcess = new ProgressBar();
```

Comment: No , that's not correct , i'm already import it as keyword `Using System.Windows.Forms.*;`